# Proof of concavity of function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ be a continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I suppose the following is *not* a sufficient condition for $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ to be concave.

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2} \leq 0, \quad \forall \boldsymbol{x} 
$$

Can someone give me a counterexample?

Comment: Should the inequality be in the other direction?

Comment: $f(x,y)=xy$ is a counterexample regardless of what exactly you meant.

Comment: @Rammus, question corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The necessary and sufficient condition for a bivariate and twice continuously differentiable function to be concave is that the Hessian matrix be negative semi definite, i.e.:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
{\partial^2 f\over \partial x^2}&{\partial^2 f\over \partial x\partial y}\\
{\partial^2 f\over \partial x\partial y}&{\partial^2 f\over \partial y^2}\\
\end{bmatrix}\preceq 0
$$which is originated from the Taylor expansion of $f(x,y)$.